# how to preview Picture with FileReader

Tags: javascript

FileReader

```
<div><img /></div>
<input name="picture[]" type="file" />
<div><img /></div>
<input name="picture[]" type="file" />
```

I have two or more  div-input pairs(like above)
But I have no idea how to match them to preview own picture.

With JavaScript, please

Comment: put your code with your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preview an image before it is uploaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this is good for you

```js
  var loadFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)"><br>
<img id="output" src="">
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. 
I Did.